Ecological temporal statistical analysis question
I collected animal samples without replacement over three time periods from the same locality: seven years apart in the deep-sea (eg, no known seasonality). I want to know whether the mean difference in viral infections changes significantly over time. The data is not normal. Would I consider this as independent (sampled without replacement, and although it's over time there are no inherent patterns eg seasonality that would contribute to variation) and therefore do a Kruskal Wallis test? Or would I need to consider the data as dependent because, although animals were sampled without replacement, they came from the same population? If the latter, are we saying that although no animal was sampled once, the removal of an individual could theoretically influence the viral infections of another in the population? And is it ok to treat the temporal aspect of the data as independent?
Would a Friedmans Test be sufficient for determining whether the mean differences are statistically significant?
Thanks!

A Friedman's test is used when your data are repeated measures / related - that is each measure is taken from one unit (animal, person, place). It doesn't sound to me like the measures are repeated / related, so a Friedman's test would not be appropriate.
Instead a Kruskal-Wallis might be appropriate. This is for unrelated measures.
However, a Kruskal-Wallis test does not compare means, it compares mean ranks - unless the distributions are the same (not necessarily normal, but the same shape), otherwise it compares mean rank.
